# Replacing input type word on button click

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have the following JS function which should change the word "hi" to "yo" on a button click if the user has input this. For example "hi, how are you today?" ==> "Yo, how are you today?"

```js
function changeWord() {
  let str = document.getElementById('inputBox').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('inputBox').innerHTML = str.replace("hi", "yo");;
}
```

The above doesn't work when I call changeWord(); on click, any ideas?

Comment: input box is a textbox? What is the HTML markup? If it is an textbox, it has a value, not innerHTML.

Comment: And just like my comments to your other question. A regular expression with word boundaries is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be targeting the value of the input rather than the HTML.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', changeWord, false);

function changeWord() {
  const str = input.value;
  input.value = str.replace("hi", "yo");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: A word of caution to OP  .. The way you are perceiving your `str.replace` -- "hi" will definately be replaced with "yo" -- BUT "him" will also become "yom" and "this" will become "tyos".  Conversely the way this is written.  "I said hi, and she said hi back" will only change the first instance .. returning "I said yo, and she said hi back"

Comment: I agree @Zak, but this answers the question. A more robust solution would probably involve regex which might be out of the OP's wheelhouse.

Answer (score 1):

Use .value instead of .innerHTML, like this:

```
let str = document.getElementById('inputBox').value;
document.getElementById('inputBox').value = str.replace("hi", "yo");
```